# A Test: Find the Missing Words!

Tags: word, enigmatic-puzzle

**Each of the following pairs of words is missing a word.

Find the missing words.**

> $$\def\T#1{\text{#1}}
> \begin{array}{rl}
> \T{A} & \T{DING}\\
> \T{CAN} & \T{GAS}\\
> \T{IN} & \T{ADS}\\
> \T{LIFE} & \T{LESS}\\
> \T{MARSH} & \T{SPICE}\\
> \T{OUT} & \T{BACK}\\
> \T{PREP} & \T{ANT}\\
> \T{PRO} & \T{FISH}\\
> \T{SCATTER} & \T{WILL}\\
> \T{SEE} & \T{ME}\\
> \T{TAX} & \T{LAND}\\
> \T{TEE} & \T{REIN}\\
> \T{UP} & \T{MAN}\\
> \T{WHERE} & \T{EVER}\\
> \T{WIN} & \T{HERE}\\
> \end{array}$$

When you're done with *that*, ...

There's a word missing from the set of missing words you found.
**What's the final missing word?**
**Why is it missing?**

For full marks ...
**What kind of test is this?**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The final missing word is...

> **their**

Explanation: The missing words for each pair

> ...create new words when they're linked to each word they're inbetween, thusly:
>
>  A **Men** Ding [Amen, Mending]
>  Can **To** Gas [Canto, Togas]
>  In **To** Ads [Into, Toads]
>  Life **Time** Less [Lifetime, Timeless]
>  Marsh **All** Spice [Marshall, Allspice]
>  Out **Come** Back [Outcome, Comeback]
>  Prep **Aid** Ant [Prepaid, Aidant]
>  Pro **Of** Fish [Proof, Offish]
>  Scatter **Good** Will [Scattergood, Goodwill]
>  See **The** Me [Seethe, Theme]
>  Tax **Is** Land [Taxis, Island]
>  Tee **The** Rein [Teethe, Therein]
>  Up **Country** Man [Upcountry, Countryman]
>  Where **For** Ever [Wherefor, Forever]
>  Win **Now** Here [Winnow, Nowhere]

And these missing words...

> combined are one word ('their') short of a known quote:
>
>  ***"Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country."***
>
>  **Their** is probably the odd one out because it's impossible to find a word that ends in 'their' (though there's *kinda* one that starts with it, 'theirselves'). And it's not in the original sentence, which was a typing exercise by Charles E. Weller (*"Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of the party"*) and an example of [filler text](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filler_text) (AKA placeholder\dummy text).

Comment: @Rubio I *think* I got your point now... ;)

Comment: Oy, my eyes. That's *not* a word. :)  ...but looks great, PSE-folk continue to amaze me at how quick things get solved!  Have a ✔ and a great day.